# Imagemagick convert doesn't convert

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, keras, operating-system, imagemagick

So my problem is in the convert from Imagemagick, this code should convert the image but it doesn't. Maybe it's because I'm on windows but idk.

I've provided the entire path as well as instead of using convert used magick but it still didn't work, it worked on the cmd but for some reason not in the program.

```py
    def display_mnist(self): # Get the png, apply color map and print to canvas
        from PIL import ImageTk, Image
        im = Image.fromarray(self.mnist_user_image*255).convert('RGB')
        im.save("E:\projects\visuals/mnist.png")
        os.system('C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16/magick.exe E:\projects\visuals/mnist.png -resize 28x28 E:\projects\visuals/mnist.png')
        self.mnist_user_image = np.array(plt.imread('E:\projects\visuals/mnist.png'),
                                                    dtype=np.float64)
```

I want the program to work, or at least not give this error: 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\projects\x0bisuals/mnist.png'

Comment: A backslash (`"\"`) in python needs to be escaped (`"\\"`). Or you need to use a raw string (`r"\"`).

Comment: Sure will try, but not rn it very late, too late for me. But it think it might work

Comment: doesn't work now I get another error: read past end of file.

Comment: I can't know what you have tried to get that new error.

Comment: I've done what you said \\

Comment: If you don't show the code, I can't help

Comment: the entire thing?

Comment: Ideally you will be able to create a [mcve].